# How do I mark tests as Passed/Skipped/Ignored in serenity?

Tags: serenity-bdd

I keep getting phantomjs error - unreachablebrowserexception.

I want to mark the test as skipped or passed in the catch block of this managed exception. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using JUnit, TestNG, any other?

Comment: @JDelorean   we're using serenity + jbehave and they use Junit runner internally

Answer (score 0):

You can use JUnit's `Assume` class at the beginning of your test to mark the test as ignored/skipped based on a condition.

For example:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {

    Assume.assumeTrue(yourBooleanCondition);

    // continue your test steps...

}
```

You can read about its different applications [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Assumptions-with-assume).

However, being able to mark a failed test as *passed* is against the test mantra and defeats the purpose of developing such code entirely. I do not know any framework that would allow you to do that. If you absolutely have to, my guess is to fiddle with the results.